# How can I update my number in while loop? (Number guessing game)

Tags: python-3.x

I am going to write a guessing game with the computer.

I choose one number in my head and the Computer is going to find it out, and it can guess between a range.
The problem is I don’t know how can I update this range during the program run.

```
import random
x = 1
y = 99
guess= random.randint(x,y)
print(guess)
play='true'
while play=='true':
    a=x
    b=y
    results = input()
    if results == 'd':
        play='false'
    else:
        if results == 'b':
            a=guess
            print('My number is bigger!')
            newguess= random.randint(a,b)
            print (newguess)
        elif results == 'k':
            b=guess
            print('My number is smaller!')
            newguess= random.randint(a,b)
            print (newguess)
print ('Wooow , computer you did it! ')
```

Comment: What range of numbers do you want?

Comment: Your guesses are chosen between `a` and `b`. If you update `a` and `b` according to each incorrect guess, it will control the range of subsequent guesses. But you keep setting `a` and `b` back to `x` and `y` so you reset the range.

Comment: overall the range of number would be between 1,99
but during the while loop I should update this range regarding to user input.
for example if the first computer guess is 25, and my number was 50.
the next computer guess would be done between (25,99). and the loop will continue until the program received 'd' from user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about all the explanations in the code but this is a version of the game that I did a while ago. What I did was I wanted to shrink the guessing range each time the user said high or low. e.g. if the computer chooses 50, and the user says 'High' then the program will not chose a number greater than 50, the same applies for 'Low". Enjoy

```
import random
count = 0 #Number of attemps. how many times while loop runs.
guess = random.randint(1,100)#The guess generator

(l,u) = (0,100) 
lower_guess = l
upper_guess = u
n = 0

print('Chose a number between ', l,  ' and ', u , '.' )


#The game. These are outside the function so that they don't print in every loop because they are unwanted for some Y inputs.
print('Is it ' + str(guess))
Y = input('Low = L, High = H and Yes = Y:')#User states

#The function

while n != 'guess':

    count +=1 #adds 1 to count each time loop runs

    if Y == 'L':
        lower_guess = guess+1
        guess = random.randint(lower_guess , upper_guess)#Redifining guess to eliminate irrelevant guesses from the range
        print('Is it ' + str(guess))
        Y = input('Low = L, High = H and Yes = Y:')

    elif Y == 'H':
        upper_guess = guess - 1
        guess = random.randint(lower_guess, upper_guess)#Redifining guess to eliminate irrelevant guesses from the range
        print('Is it ' + str(guess))
        Y = input('Low = L, High = H and Yes = Y:')


    elif Y == 'Y':
        print('I guessed it in ' + str(count) + ' attempts')
        break

    else:
        count = 0
        lower_guess = l
        upper_guess = u
        guess = random.randint(1,100)
        print('That input was invalid. The game has restarted.')
        print('You can chose a new number or keep your old one.')
        print('Is it ' + str(guess))
        Y = input('Low = L, High = H and Yes = Y:')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot no problem :D its more understandable for me with this comment.